# Grub crashes when installing windows 10

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I tried installing Windows 10 alongside my existing installation of Ubuntu 14.04. Everything was working fine till I rebooted my system for the second time.

Firstly, the GRUB menu shows Windows 7 instead of Windows 10. Could it be because installation did not complete? Moreover, when I try to launch it, I just end up with a black screen. I tried to perform boot repair but it didn't work. Here is the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14853120

Comment: I have edited your question. Please see if I have got any detail wrong. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for my bad formulation, it's pretty clear now ! :)